# Proving Lagranges Thorem

Tags: group-theory

Im trying to understand Lagranges theorem.There is this group G and subgroup H.
I have the right coset of H (order m)

I have this statement in the proof

Let

[image]

*which is impossible*

---

What do they mean by this stament .. i really dont understand.
Why do they take `hia=hya?` and what is impossible ?

UPDATE:
[image]

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: @fkraiem Some Notes i Have

Comment: No idea what a "NoteBook" is, but you should probably get a proper textbook, or just use Google. Judging just from the typesetting, this doesn't look like a good source. It's impossible to know what this means without (at least) the complete text of the proof.

Comment: @fkraiem Please see the update

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that's just bad wording. The elements of $H$ are $h_1,h_2,\dots,h_m$, they are all distinct so if $i\ne j$, then $h_i \ne h_j$. The elements of the coset $Ha$ are $h_1a,h_2a,\dots,h_ma$ and we want to show again that they are all distinct, that is, if $i\ne j$, then $h_ia\ne h_ja$. For contradiction, suppose there is some $i,j$ such that $i\ne j$ and $h_ia = h_ja$. Then by multiplicating by $a^{-1}$ on the right, we obtain $h_i = h_j$. This is a contradiction, because since $i\ne j$, we know that $h_i \ne h_j$.

Comment: okay..little bit confusing though.I will see some other proof in the textbook and get back.